# How to calculate this integral involving ratio of exponents?

Tags: integration

I am trying to replicate some math in a statistics paper (section 2.2, Lin et al Biometrics, 1998).

We first know 
\begin{align*}
\int^{\infty}_{-\infty} e^{\gamma_x u}  \frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}} \text{exp}\{-\frac{(u-\mu_{x,z})^2}{2}\} du = \text{exp} (\gamma_x \mu_{x,z}+0.5 \gamma_x^2)
\end{align*}

and,
\begin{align*}
\text{Pr}(Y=1|X,Z)=\text{exp}(\alpha+\beta X+\theta Z)\int^{\infty}_{-\infty} \frac{e^{\gamma_x u}}{1+\text{exp}(\alpha+\beta X + \gamma_x u + \theta Z)} d F(u|X,Z)
\end{align*}

Now assume $\text{Pr}(Y=1|X,Z)$ takes a new form:

$\text{logit}\{\text{Pr}(Y=1|X,Z)\} =\alpha+\beta X+\theta Z+g(X,Z) $

We need to find an expression of this function $g(X,Z)$. The paper said the procedure is very simple calculus and the answer is:
\begin{align*}
g(X,Z) &=\gamma_x \mu_{x,z}+0.5\gamma_x^2+\text{log} \frac{\int^{\infty}_{-\infty} \frac{1}{1+\text{exp}(\alpha+\gamma^2_x+\beta X + \gamma_x u + \theta Z)} d F(u|X,Z) }{\int^{\infty}_{-\infty} \frac{1}{1+\text{exp}(\alpha+\beta X + \gamma_x u + \theta Z)} d F(u|X,Z)}
\end{align*}

What I did:

\begin{align*}
\text{logit}\{\text{Pr}(Y=1|X,Z)\} &=\alpha+\beta X+\theta Z+g(X,Z) \\
&\leftrightarrow \\
\frac{\text{exp}(\alpha+\beta X+\theta Z + g(X,Z))}{1+\text{exp}(\alpha+\beta X+\theta Z + g(X,Z))} &=\text{exp}(\alpha+\beta X+\theta Z)\int^{\infty}_{-\infty} \frac{e^{\gamma_x u}}{1+\text{exp}(\alpha+\beta X + \gamma_x u + \theta Z)} d F(u|X,Z) \\
&\leftrightarrow \\
\frac{\text{exp}(g(X,Z))}{1+\text{exp}(\alpha+\beta X+\theta Z) \text{exp}(g(X,Z))} &=\int^{\infty}_{-\infty} \frac{e^{\gamma_x u}}{1+\text{exp}(\alpha+\beta X + \gamma_x u + \theta Z)} d F(u|X,Z) \\
&\leftrightarrow \\
\text{exp}(g(X,Z))&=\int^{\infty}_{-\infty} \frac{e^{\gamma_x u}}{1+\text{exp}(\alpha+\beta X + \gamma_x u + \theta Z)} d F(u|X,Z) \\
&+\text{exp}(g(X,Z))\int^{\infty}_{-\infty} \frac{\text{exp}(\alpha+\beta X +\gamma_x u+\theta Z)}{1+\text{exp}(\alpha+\beta X + \gamma_x u + \theta Z)} d F(u|X,Z) \\
&\leftrightarrow \\
\text{exp}(g(X,Z)) &=\frac{\int^{\infty}_{-\infty} \frac{e^{\gamma_x u}}{1+\text{exp}(\alpha+\beta X + \gamma_x u + \theta Z)} d F(u|X,Z) }{1-\int^{\infty}_{-\infty} \frac{\text{exp}(\alpha+\beta X +\gamma_x u+\theta Z)}{1+\text{exp}(\alpha+\beta X + \gamma_x u + \theta Z)} d F(u|X,Z) } \\
&\leftrightarrow \\
\text{exp}(g(X,Z)) &=\frac{\int^{\infty}_{-\infty} \frac{e^{\gamma_x u}}{1+\text{exp}(\alpha+\beta X + \gamma_x u + \theta Z)} d F(u|X,Z) }{\int^{\infty}_{-\infty} \frac{1}{1+\text{exp}(\alpha+\beta X + \gamma_x u + \theta Z)} d F(u|X,Z)} \\
&\leftrightarrow \\
g(X,Z) &=\text{log} \frac{\int^{\infty}_{-\infty} \frac{e^{\gamma_x u}}{1+\text{exp}(\alpha+\beta X + \gamma_x u + \theta Z)} d F(u|X,Z) }{\int^{\infty}_{-\infty} \frac{1}{1+\text{exp}(\alpha+\beta X + \gamma_x u + \theta Z)} d F(u|X,Z)}
\end{align*}

Here, $F(u|X,Z)$ is distribution function for $N(\mu_{x,z},1)$. However, I can not see how
$\int^{\infty}_{-\infty} \frac{e^{\gamma_x u}}{1+\text{exp}(\alpha+\beta X + \gamma_x u + \theta Z)} d F(u|X,Z) $ can become $ \text{exp} (\gamma_x \mu_{x,z}+0.5\gamma_x^2){\int^{\infty}_{-\infty} \frac{1}{1+\text{exp}(\alpha+\gamma^2_x+\beta X + \gamma_x u + \theta Z)} d F(u|X,Z) } $ to get the author's conclusion.

\begin{align*}
g(X,Z) &=\int^{\infty}_{-\infty} \frac{e^{\gamma_x u}}{1+\text{exp}(\alpha+\beta X + \gamma_x u + \theta Z)} d F(u|X,Z) \\
&=\int^{\infty}_{-\infty}\frac{1}{1+\text{exp}(\alpha+\beta X + \gamma_x u + \theta Z)} e^{\gamma_x u}  \frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}} \text{exp}\{-\frac{(u-\mu_{x,z})^2}{2}\} du \\
&=\int^{\infty}_{-\infty}\frac{1}{1+\text{exp}(\alpha+\beta X + \gamma_x u + \theta Z)} \text{exp}(0.5 \gamma^2_x+\gamma_x \mu_x)\frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}} \text{exp}\{-\frac{(u-(\mu_{x,z}+\gamma_x))^2}{2}\} du \\
&=\text{exp}(0.5 \gamma^2_x+\gamma_x \mu_x) \int^{\infty}_{-\infty}\frac{1}{1+\text{exp}(\alpha+\beta X + \gamma_x u + \theta Z)} \frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}} \text{exp}\{-\frac{(u-(\mu_{x,z}+\gamma_x))^2}{2}\} du
\end{align*}

Ok, I figured it out.

We let $k=u-\gamma_x$, then $g(X,Z)$ becomes

\begin{align*}
g(X,Z) &=\text{exp}(0.5 \gamma^2_x+\gamma_x \mu_x) \int^{\infty}_{-\infty}\frac{1}{1+\text{exp}(\alpha+\beta X + \gamma_x (k+\gamma_x)+ \theta Z)} \frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}} \text{exp}\{-\frac{(k-\mu_{x,z}))^2}{2}\} dk \\
&=\text{exp}(0.5 \gamma^2_x+\gamma_x \mu_x) \int^{\infty}_{-\infty}\frac{1}{1+\text{exp}(\alpha+\beta X + \gamma_x k+\gamma_x^2)+ \theta Z)} \frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}} \text{exp}\{-\frac{(k-\mu_{x,z}))^2}{2}\} dk \\
\end{align*}